# How to use std::pair with classes?

Tags: c++, std-pair

so I'm experimenting with [cvc5](https://cvc5.github.io/) and just wanted to keep track of the `Term`s in a map so I have created this:

`std::map<std::string, std::pair<Term, int>> terms;`

Basically, for I used the `name` as an index and I store the `Term` with other info in the map.

I have created a subtype of `Term` called `TermStruct` and I wanted to create another similar map:

`std::map<std::string, std::pair<TermStruct, int>> termsStructs;`

`TermStruct` was created roughly in the following way

```
class  TermStruct : public Term {
public:
    TermStruct(Term *t) : Term() {
        this->t = t;
    }
    
    bool isNull();
    Term *getTerm() { return this->t; };
    
    std::string toString();
    
private:
    
    Term *t = nullptr;

};
```

Now when I tried to add a new element to the `termStructs` map in the following way:

```
termsStructs[str] = std::pair(term, offset);
```

*Note*: `term` is of the correct type.

I have a number of compilation error such as:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_map.h:501:37:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::pair<TermStruct, int>; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<TermStruct, int> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::pair<TermStruct, int>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
/home/alberto/progetti/llvm/plugin/runtime/cvc5/Runtime.cpp:113:25:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/tuple:1824:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<TermStruct, int>::pair()’
 1824 |         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)
```

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::pair<Term, int>> terms;` What's `Term`?

Comment: HI @John, it is a class which is part of `cvc5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pair` has nothing to do with this problem. It is all about `map`. I see two options.

1. Introduce a default constructor(a constructor without parameters) for `TermStruct` if you want to use `std::map::operator[]`. Here's why:

   - `termsStructs[str] = std::pair(term, offset)` does not insert the pair object right away
   - `termsStructs[str]` first creates a new key-value pair and adds it to the map(if there is no entry for `str`)
   - It is done by running `std::make_pair(key, T())`
   - As `T` here is `std::pair`, it tries to call `Term()` (FYI the second(integer) is zero-initialized)
   - However there is no `Term()` defined - compiler error

You may refer these links for details.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at (1)
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair (1)

2. Or you can use `emplace` or `insert`.

These methods look uglier than the above but they behave just like what you must have expected. It does not require a default constructor.

For example,

```cpp
termsStructs.emplace(str, std::pair(term, offset));
termsStructs.insert({str, std::pair(term, offset)});
```